# What is the correct way of doing modulo 10^9+7?

Tags: java, algorithm

How to get the correct modulo for the following piece of code. I am stuck here. I am using typecasts to get my result. I need to return `int`. What is the correct way.

```
int m = 1000000007;
long res=0L;
if(numOne > 3)
  res = (parts[1] - parts[0]) * (parts[3] - parts[2]);
return (int)res%m;
```

`parts` array store integers, `res` is long. The above multiplication result gets overflowed and thus `res` turns negative. Without typecasting what is the best way of doing so..

```
res = (long)(parts[1] - parts[0]) * (long)(parts[3] - parts[2]);
```

The above code works fine.

Comment: Apply the modulus to each coefficient prior to multiplication, then again for the final result.

Comment: Even if you mod each multiplicand, `parts[1] - parts[0]` could still overflow.

Comment: But (10^9 + 6)^2 still overflows 2^32, so I think you would have to cast to long for the multiplication anyway. If you really need to avoid longs you can implement the multiplication yourself with bitwise shifts (and a mod after each shift) and sums, but I doubt it's worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modulo before multiplication as your current implementation might overflow in some cases:

```
int m = 1000000007;
long res = 0L;
if (numOne > 3)
    res = ((parts[1] - parts[0] + m) % m) * ((parts[3] - parts[2] + m) % m);
return res % m;
```

Reference: [here](https://youtu.be/-OPohCQqi_E)

Answer (score 1):

Use utility function for modular operations.
And cast `int`s to `long`s before any operation.

```java
long mod(long n){
   return (a % m + m) % m;
}
res = mod(mod((long)parts[1] - parts[0]) * mod((long)parts[3] - parts[2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overflow, you need need to apply the mod to each side of the multiplication and cast each side of the multiplication to long (or better, change parts to be an array of long)

```
res = (long)(parts[1] - parts[0])%m * (long)(parts[3] - parts[2])%m;
```

Comment: I see that is the only correct way I guess!

Comment: ```parts[1] - parts[0]``` could still cause issues if ```parts[1] < parts[0]``` as it will result in a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

In *general case*, there are several possibilities for *integer overflow* which can lead to incorrect answer:

```
parts[1] - parts[0]
```

can exceed `Integer.maxValue` / `Integer.minValue` (e.g. `-1_000_000_000 - 2_000_000_000`), that's why we should cast to `long`:

```
(long)parts[1] - parts[0]
```

then

```
(parts[1] - parts[0]) * (parts[3] - parts[2])
```

can exceed `Long.maxValue` and we have to compute remainder from each term:

```
((long)parts[1] - parts[0]) % m
((long)parts[3] - parts[2]) % m
```

Finally

```
res = ((((long)parts[1] - parts[0]) % m) * (((long)parts[3] - parts[2]) % m)) % m;
```

if any term can be *negative* and you want *non-negative* `res`:

```
res = (((((long)parts[1] - parts[0]) % m) * 
        (((long)parts[3] - parts[2]) % m)) % m + m) % m;
```